# Bypass windows built in function

Tags: windows

I have built a software using java that uses credit based accounting system to control printer. I want to bypass the native printing software which is built in in windows. That means, if i press ctrl+P, windows will launch my software. How to do it?

Comment: You must modify the registry to reassign the "print" verb.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you do is read a Windows programming primer (Charles Petzold book is good) that will teach you how to program, program Windows and that way you'll be able to work it out for yourself, without getting somebody else to give you all the answers to a very complicated problem.